# Using hapijs as an express middleware

Tags: express, hapi.js

Is there a way to add hapi as a middleware in an express app?

It could work like so:

```
var app = express();
var api = hapi.Server();

app.use('/api', api.expressHandler);
app.get('/', renderHandler);
```